# GCE VM can't connect to TPU

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tpu

I've been following the instruction at https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/custom-setup

and now I'm trying to run a tiny example from https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart

But it hangs on `sess.run(tpu.initialize_system())`

I suspect that it can't access the TPU network endpoint, even though "gcloud beta compute tpus list" returns status "READY".

Comment: I'm having same problem with TF2.2.  
I create the TPU + VM with `ctpu up --zone=europe-west4-a --disk-size-gb=50 --machine-type=n1-standard-2 --tf-version=2.2 --tpu-size v3-8 --name cola-tpu` but when I run `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolv
er('cola-tpu'); tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)"` it hangs forever... The current answer is not helpful.

Comment: @Astariul I am having similar issue with JAX